# How to write SQL - check for A5 Or if not exist then A6 AND A7

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL code which prints message like particular attachment is missing.

For example, pseudo code is below :-

```
SELECT 'A1' AS MSG WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)
UNION    
SELECT 'A2' AS MSG WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)
UNION
SELECT 'A3' AS MSG WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)
UNION
SELECT 'A4' AS MSG WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)
```

All these messages I am storing it in a variable in **","** appended format which I will be using further for printing.

Now I want to union with one conditional message, check for A5 Or if not exist then A6 AND A7.

I tried coding the scenario but with no luck. How can I simply achieve this ?

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: Where is your from? and what do you mean? if a5 not exists select a6,a7 and if it does select a5?

Comment: Check out for CASE statement ... that's what you need

Comment: @sagi, 1] It is a pseudo code. 2] From is not required in my case. I am selecting a message only if the where not exists condition goes true. 3] If A5 exists, not required to validate for A6 & A7. Does this explains the scenario ?

Comment: So when exactly do you want to generate this message? Only in case neither A5, A6 or A7 exist? Or in case A5+A6 or A5+A7 are missing? or what else?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, It is simply, if the attachment A5 is there, no need to check for attachments A6 & A7. Or if attachment A5 is not there, then attachments A6 & A7 both must present.

Comment: And is it fixed messages you are talking about? So pseudo code would rather be `SELECT 'A1 message' AS MSG WHERE NOT EXISTS (<A1 query>)`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, that's correct. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's okay when either A5 or A6+A7 exist:

```
Okay = EXISTS(A5) OR ( EXISTS(A6) AND EXISTS(A7) )
```

This translates to:

```
Not okay = NOT EXISTS(A5) AND ( NOT EXISTS(A6) OR NOT EXISTS(A7) )
```

In the query:

```
UNION
SELECT 'A5+A6/A7' AS MSG WHERE NOT EXISTS (<A5 query>)
                         AND ( NOT EXISTS(<A6 query>) OR NOT EXISTS(<A7 query>) )
```

So you tell the DBMS *what* to check, but you cannot really tell it in what order to do it. The DBMS may decide to do the A6 test first, if it thinks this performs better than to start with the A5 check. But this is nothing we should worry about. Important to us is only to get the correct result. To find the best execution path is not our business.

Comment: Great ! it worked. Thanks a lot :). Can it be modified to show the exact message like A5 is missing or A7 is missing ?

Comment: A5 is always missing when you show that message. But you want to know whether only A6 or A7 or both A6 and A7 are missing? You'd have to build separate queries for each such message, e.g. for A5+A6 missing and A7 present: `SELECT 'A5+A6 missing' AS MSG WHERE NOT EXISTS (<A5 query>) AND NOT EXISTS(<A6 query>) AND EXISTS(<A7 query>)`